# Powershell Downloadfile and start process

Tags: powershell

I'm using this code to Downloadfile and i want to run the file after download it at the same code .

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "" -OutFile "" ; start-process -FilePath ""
```

i'm suing start-process after the code but not working .

Comment: Well, you need to supply a URL and some file paths :)

Comment: yes i know that i put the url and the file path and that's work in the Powershell window but in other application doesn't work like Microsoft Word in macro page .

Comment: Show us the macro you use to run the powershell script then